# How to group multiple rows based on some criteria and sum values in R?

Tags: r

---

[image: data snapshot]

---

Hi All,
Example :- The above is the data I have.  I want to group age 1-2 and count the values. In this data value is 4 for age group 1-2. Similarly I want to group age 3-4 and count the values. Here the value for age group 3-4 is 6.

How can I group age and aggregate the values correspond to it?

I know this way: code-

```
data.frame(df %>% group_by(df$Age) %>% tally())
```

But the values are aggregating on individual Age.
I want the values aggregating on multiple age to be a group as mentioned above example.

Any help on this will be greatly helpful.
Thanks a lot to All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions, with base R and with package `dplyr`.
I will use the data posted by [Shree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568268/how-to-group-multiple-rows-based-on-some-criteria-and-sum-values-in-r/53568302#53568302).

**First**, base R.
I create a grouping variable `grp` and then `aggregate` on it.

```
grp <- with(df, c((age %in% 1:2) + 2*(age %in% 3:4)))
aggregate(age ~ grp, df, length)
#  grp age
#1   1   4
#2   2   6
```

**Second** a `dplyr` way.
Function `case_when` is used to create a grouping variable. This allows for meaningful names to be given to the groups in an easy way.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(grp = case_when(
    age %in% 1:2 ~ "2:3",
    age %in% 3:4 ~ "3:4",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  tally()
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  grp       n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 1:2       4
#2 3:4       6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `dplyr` and `?cut` from base R -

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 Name = letters[1:10],
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>% 
  count(grp = cut(age, breaks = c(0,2,4)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  grp       n
  <fct> <int>
1 (0,2]     4
2 (2,4]     6
```